# Fundamental Matrix with Sums

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, summation

Let $$\Phi(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11}(t) & x_{12}(t)\\
x_{21}(t) & x_{22}(t)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
be a fundamental matrix for 
$$x'=A(t)$$
where 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}(t) & a_{12}(t)\\
a_{21}(t) & a_{22}(t)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Show that:
$$
(\det Φ)'=\left(\det\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_1^2 a_{1k}x_{k1} & \sum_1^2 a_{1k}x_{k2}\\
x_{21} & x_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
+ \det\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12}\\
\sum_1^2 a_{2k}x_{k1} & \sum_1^2 a_{2k}x_{k2}
\end{bmatrix}\right)= \sum_1^2 a_{ii}\detΦ $$

Answer (score 0):

I was going to put this in a comment, but it's a little longer than what comments should be:

All I think you need here is that $\det$ is a multilinear operator on the column vectors of matrices and so you have the product rule to work with.  For instance, if $x_1(t) = (x_{11}(t),x_{12}(t))$ and $x_2(t) = (x_{12}(t),x_{22}(t))$, then

$$
\det(\Phi(t))' = \det(x_1(t), x_2(t))' = \det(x_1'(t), x_2(t)) + \det(x_1(t), x_2'(t))
$$

Use the fact that $x_1'(t) = A(t)x_1(t)$ and $x_2'(t) = A(t)x_2(t)$ here and substitute to get:

$$
\det(\Phi(t))' = \det(A(t)x_1(t),x_2(t)) + \det(x_1(t), A(t)x_2(t)).
$$

Does this help?